# Azure Table query with only RowKey

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a table with **~10,000 PartitionKey** (PK) and each PK has **~500,000 RowKey** (RK) as "yyyyMMddHHmmss"

### short

When I try to retrieve records with "yyyyMMdd" formatted RK without PK, it takes forever (literally) to get results.

### long

My queries are mostly PK + RK unfortunately some queries must be retrieved by RK only.
I understand that retrieving data without PK is not the best approach but I have to.
And it looks like this is not an option at all in real life scenario.

The only way I can think of is keeping another table to save PKs based on RK's which I really don't want to keep reference table unless it is absolutely the only way to handle this)

### code

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
table.CreateIfNotExists();
var query = new TableQuery<TestEntity>().Where("(RowKey ge '20050103') and (RowKey lt '20050104')");
var result = table.ExecuteQuery(query);

Debug.WriteLine(result.Count());
```

Comment: Could you explain what prevents the PK from being used in your sample query? Is it time based and you don't know the time?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson PK is name and RK is datetime. Request may come as combination like name only, name + datetime, date only. Last option is the problem part.

Comment: I ended up including PK in the beginning of the RK. That way I can always extract PK from the RK string. That won't work for queries accross several PK's of course.

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly noted, for such volume of data, retrieval without a PK is not feasible.

If retrieval by date-only is necessary, as painful as it sounds, I would say that the design of your table schema is flawed and needs to be redesigned.  If you wish to explain all of the usage scenarios for the data in the table, perhaps folks here can help with the proper design of the table?

Comment: Thank you @Igorek  I have name and datetime fields to use my data, so either i will use PK as name and RK as datetime or vice versa. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I meant more from an overall use-case to understand if there are some alternatives to the current PK/RK schema

Comment: I'm certain that there is no other way so looking for a solution in this design. Actually, I was wondering if there is some kind of switch like UseNagleAlgorithm etc.  Thanks again

Comment: Any tuning you can do to networking stack or serialization is retrieval of data that you've already selected... however, if you're going at this table with queries that have no partition key, the scans will be crazy slow and no tuning can fix that

Comment: I realize you think that there are no other design solutions but have you truly exhausted every possibility?  ATS tables are not relational.  Have you considered saving two copies of data with different PK's in the same table? Concatenating names and dates in some fashion? having daily/monthly tables or PK/RK strategies, etc?

Comment: Table contains classic stock fields which are (ticker [PK],datetime[RK],open,high,low,close,quantity,amount) and since there are millions of data in hand, repeating that data will be a risky play due to the possible consistency issues. Regardless of the making connection count double, I prefer to use reference table instead if it comes to that. 99.99% times i have to call query with ticker name and only 0.01% with datetime alone.  But you are right, that is another option that I can use.  Thank you!

Comment: Stupid question, but have you considered flipping the PK/RK fields?  Store "DateTime.MaxValue - Date's Ticks" in the PK and ticker in the RK?  If your PK's Tick values are descending all you have to do is "Take 1" from a query that looks like this: PartitionKey <= 'my date' and RowKey == 'ticker'.  Such queries will be  99% of the calls.  And the other time when you need to do a call on Timestamp only, you just reference PK as needed. You can also store the minute's Ticks of the date, not batch a few prices togehter within a minute. Let me know if this makes sense or you need a fuller write-up

Comment: It does make sense but not for me on this case. Data is really big and 0.01% won't worth to add additional info into PK. Plus, that method will force me to give up EQUAL operator on PK which would be a big deal on performance side.  Reference table and duplicated table with flipped PK/RK are the workarounds for this problem not actual solution. Thx again.